# Find uniques timestamp in array of different sizes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multi index pandas dataframe looks like this:

```
df["Name"] = ["A","B","C","D"]
df["Quantity"] = [2,1.2,1.3,3]
df["Date1"] = ["2019-04-04","2019-08-08","2018-08-30","2017-03-02"]
df["Date2"] = ["2019-05-16","2020-05-01","2018-09-13",pd.DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-18', '2018-12-13'])]

df
Name Quantity  Date1          Date2
 A     2       2019-04-04   2019-05-16
 B     1.2     2019-08-08   2020-05-01
 C     1.3     2018-08-30   2018-09-13
 D     3       2017-03-02   DatetimeIndex('2018-10-18', '2018-12-13'])
```

I want to select unique values in Date1 and Date2 columns. The end result should look like this:

```
Name  2017-03-02  2018-08-30  2018-09-13  2018-10-18  2018-12-13  2019-04-04  2019-05-16  2019-08-08  2020-05-01
A                                                                    2                      
B                                                                                           1.2
C                    1.3        
D       2
```

I have tried to ravel Date1,Date2 columns, but it doesn't ravel the DatetimeIndex array

```
df[["Date1","Date2"]].values.ravel()

[Out]
array(['2019-04-04', '2019-05-16', '2019-08-08', '2020-05-01',
       '2018-08-30', '2018-09-13', '2017-03-02',
       DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-18', '2018-12-13'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)],
      dtype=object)
```

Also, how can I map the dates with the values in quantity column?

Comment: nesting a datetimeindex inside a dataframe is unwise. Why do you do like that?

Comment: I have some rules before that return either a list / array or a date. If the datetimeindex is instead a list of dates, what how should it be done to ravel?

Comment: What I meant is that when possible, you should not nest lists / tuples / whatever in a dataframe element. They cannot be easily manipulated. I would try to have a dataframe where you have an extra row, with another Name `D`, Quantity `3` and Date1 whatever is it rather than packing two `Date2` together.

Comment: The elements in Date2 are not in equal sizes, some rows have list of 6 elements or more ...